# Fetch data from mail app in your metro application

Tags: xaml, microsoft-metro

Is it possible to fetch data from 3rd party metro application into my application? e.g. I am trying to find out if my metro application can fetch email data from a specific user. Is it really possible by implementing sharing contract?

Comment: do you want to communicate Mail app specificaly or you are just giving example of Mail app ?

Comment: I want my app to communicate with Metro app. e.g. Currently have facility to share the data of my app through Mail app. However i am trying to implement the functionality where my app should be able to communicate with Mail app and should be able to find out if there are any mails that has been received through a specific user.

Comment: No you can't do that. You can't communicate it such a way. If any provides such feature than you can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks xyroid. This is not possible. Closing this thread.